# Is "look forward for" a correct phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage

I saw this sentence on an exam paper: "*I'm looking forward for your letter*".

I think it's wrong. It should be "*I'm looking forward to your letter*". I searched on the web. I did find someone said 'look forward for' is possible. So, I'm not so clear about it now. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Looking forward *to*** is correct and is often followed by a word ending in "ing" (but not necessarily).  "I look forward to having dinner with you" or "I look forward to your visit".  As previously stated, for + that which is (possibly) anticipated.

It's awkward but I did locate some uses of "for" following "forward" where forward is used as the adverb "in front of".  One example, "I am looking behind me for the police and looking forward for traffic problems".  However, it was noted that "ahead of" would be perhaps a better word to use in that sentence as opposed to "forward".  Actually, as I think about it (and look at it in it's adverb form) I can see some other appropriate uses of "for". "I drove slowly forward for fear I might miss running over my husband".  Meh, even there I think "in" might be better than "for".

Forward adverb
Definition of forward (Entry 2 of 4)
: to or toward what is ahead or in front
from that time forward
moved slowly forward

Merriam Webster

Personally, I'm looking *forward* to being informed that I answered this question in accordance with the forum's rules and policies.

Comment: based on the inputs I got so far, I assume "I'm looking forward for your letter" is an incorrect use.

Comment: Correct.  But you're welcome to look forward to receiving the letter.

Answer (score 3):

When the context is anticipation:

**look forward to** + {that which is anticipated}

Comment: So, look forward for is wrong?

Answer (score -2):

If an action (verb) is anticipated, then ‘to’ is used and if it's a noun, then ‘for’ is used.

For example, “I’m looking forward to getting your letter.” Or, “I'm looking forward for your letter.”

Comment: It is more common to say ...looking forward to your letter.